# How to access specific discord.js audit logs with an index

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to find a solution on how I can access a specific discord.js audit log at a specific index. This is an example of what I mean:

```
fetchedLogs = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
//"message" refers to the message that the client received
                    limit: 10,
                    type: MEMBER_BAN_ADD
                });
```

This is a function to log the executor, target and the reason of the log of each of the logs in `fetchedLogs` to the console.

```
function logFilter(l){
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        const { executor, target, reason } = e.entries[i]
        const logResult = `Executor: ${executor}\n Target: ${target}\n Reason: ${reason}`
        console.log(logResult)
    }
}

logFilter(fetchedLogs)
```

This is the error after it was ran:

```
const { executor, target, reason } = l.entries[i]
        ^

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'executor' of 'l.entries[i]' as it is undefined.
```

Basically, the problem I ran into is that I am unable to refer to the specific audit log. This can be proven because when I run this instead of `const { executor, target, reason } = l.entries[i]` , it doesn't output an error:

```
const { executor, target, reason } = l.entries.first()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's a `Collection`. You can use `Collection#at()` to fix that:

```js
const { executor, target, reason } = l.entries.at(i)
```